# average calculation for many data in R

Tags: r, mean

I have a file to which the results are saved:

```
4
4
4       
4
5

4
4
5
6
4

4
5
5
6
4
```

I would like to calculate the average for each group

unfortunately, only I managed to calculate for everyone
I would like to get an average of 5 items

they are savedin wynik2.txt file

```
wynik_epidemii  <- read.table(file="wynik2.txt")
wynik_epidemii<- mean(as.numeric(unlist(wynik_epidemii)))
```

Comment: Where is this data saved? How is it saved? How will it be imported into R? I can't really answer this without knowing these things

Comment: they are savedin wynik2.txt file
`wynik_epidemii  <- read.table(file="wynik2.txt")`
`wynik_epidemii<- mean(as.numeric(unlist(wynik_epidemii)))`

Comment: Can you post the data in your question

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tapply`, defining the grouping factor with a `cumsum` trick.

```
meanN <- function(x, n = 5){
  f <- cumsum(rep(c(1, rep(0, n - 1)), length.out = length(x)))
  tapply(x, f, mean)
}

meanN(x)
#  1   2   3 
#4.2 4.6 4.8
```

**DATA.**

```
x <-
  c(4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4)
```

Comment: We don't know whether he's storing the data in a single vector, or in a dataframe. I would hold off answering until we get a more clear picture